# I have a problem when using eclipse CDT debugger, it stops at first printf

Tags: c++, c, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to debug a program that merges to ordered one dimensional arrays, the merge function doesn't run as expected and I want to use the debugger to solve the problem but when I'm stepping over the instructions the debugger seems to hang on the first printf.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void input(int * array, int length);
void sort(int * array, int length);
int * merge(int * array1, int * array2, int a, int b, int * merged);
void output(int * array, int length);

int main(void){
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    int N, M, n[20], m[20], merged[40];

    printf("Enter length of first series N <= 20 ");
    scanf("%d",&N);

    input(n, N);
    sort(n,N);
    output(n,N);

    ....
```

When I run the step over function of the first `printf` I get:

```
Enter length of first series N <= 20 *stopped,reason="end-stepping-range",frame={addr="0x00401455",func="main",args=[],file="..\main.cpp"....
```

Than after trying to input 5 on the console nothing happens and the step over function is grayed out. Trying to use `fflush(stdout)` causes similar behavior it just hangs on the `fflush` function.

What could be the problem?

Comment: It does not hang. It is awaiting input!!!

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please remember the *minimal* part of your [mcve]. Almost none of the code shown is relevant to the problem.

Comment: Also, be aware that C and C++ are different languages. Only tag the language you are actually developing in.

Comment: The console of Eclipse is known for not being a real terminal. I'm not sure about the current state, or the state of the version you are using, but you might consider another way of providing input or debugging.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong in your function work, as you haven't shown the work of the functions no one will be able tot tell what's wrong.
After the input is taken the value is sent to the function till that point it works fine according to your explanation, so there is some error in your function work that compiler is failing to understand.